# javascript: get index of image clicked that is stored in an array of images

Tags: javascript, image, slider, indexof

Im making a pop up image slider, when the thumbnail of that image is clicked a pop up displays with that same image. I need to find a way to grab the index of the clicked image in my "imgArr" and then start the slide at that current index. my code makes the slider go from the current image clicked back to index 1 then 2 and so on... Its always starting at index 0 no matter what image I click

**extra info**: my imgArr variable changes its array depending on which page its currently on. so there are 3 other variables containing different types images but those variables get updated to imgArr so javascript can decide where to post images.

[codepen](https://codepen.io/Andyg123/pen/GBLJjx)

```
 let imgArr;
 var current = 0;

 rightArrow.addEventListener('click', slideRight);

 function slideRight(){
   popImg.setAttribute('src', imgArr[current + 1]);
   current++;
   if(current > imgArr.length){
     current = 0;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Your codepen example raises an error.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you have an array of images and you want the index of the image clicked to be returned.

Unfortunately i'm not home right now to test this right now but I believe it should do what you're looking for.

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    images[i].onclick = function (img) {
        var index = imgArr.findIndex(image => image === img.src);
        console.log(index + ' clicked.');
    }
}
```

Comment: close, but it logs -1 clicked on every image clicked. I just need to let JavaScript know to slide right at the current image clicked and not go back to index 0  of that array and start sliding there when client clicks right arrow. but Thank you so much

Comment: Can you show me what your array content looks like? My code looks for the exact img `src=""` inside the array. If it's returning -1 it means it is not finding anything that matches.